# overflow of slides container error when page run in wordpress

Tags: jssor

I'm trying to implement the banner slider on this page which is a wordpress site.  If I run the page locally it runs fine, but when I run the page from the site, I get the following error - Uncaught Error: Overflow of slides container wrong specification, it should be specified as 'hidden' (style='overflow:hidden;').

http://www.wood-west.com/slider-test/

Any idea what's going wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your page, right click on the page and click 'View page source' item on the context menu, and find the following line.

```
<div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 650px; height: 284px;<br />
            overflow: hidden;">
```

You will see an extra `<br />` is in your code, please remove it.

Comment: Thank you!  Gotta love wordpress.